# jQuery.ajax (1.4.3) jsonp call not removing callback script from head tag

Tags: jquery, rest, service, jsonp

I am using jQuery 1.4.3 to make an ajax call to an ASP.NET MVC 2 rest service.  Since this rest service is on a different domain, I have to use jsonp.  The issue I am running into is after upgrading from jQuery 1.4.2 to 1.4.3, I now get javascript errors when jQuery tries to remove the  tag that was injected for the jsonp callback.  The data from the rest service comes back fine.

After looking at the jQuery 1.4.3 file, i see that the error is occuring at this line:

```
if ( head ) {
     head.removeChild( script );
}
```

After debugging that section in firebug, this is what happening.  After the first ajax jsonp call to method getDetail(), the "script" variable has the following value which is in the "head" variable, so the call "head.removeChild(script);" suceeds and the script tag is removed.

```
<script src="http://localhost:63505/Locations/Detail/445?callback=fetchLocationInfoWindowCallback"></script>
```

On a Subsequent call to the same method getDetail() using ajax jsonp again, looking in the debugger, the "script" variable still has the following value, however the "head" variable no longer contains this script tag.

```
<script src="http://localhost:63505/Locations/Detail/445?callback=fetchLocationInfoWindowCallback"></script>
```

Instead this "script" variable should have the following value which is contained within the "head" variable.

```
<script src="http://localhost:63505/Locations/Detail/335?callback=fetchLocationInfoWindowCallback"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

The [jQuery 1.4.4 RC](http://blog.jquery.com/2010/11/03/jquery-1-4-4-release-candidate-2-released/) has a fix for this problem.

Comment: that is exactly the problem I am having, thanks!  However when i try using the new jquery found at http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4rc2.js, the same issue still exists.